# Opening Azure DataFactory Projects in VS2015

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am working on a solution that apparently was created in VS2013.  I have VS2015 installed.  There are a number of .dfproj files included in the solution.  When I attempt to load the solution it tells me that .dfproj files are unsupported.  I have the latest Azure SDK installed.  I also located a download for the "Azure Data Factory Visual Studio Tools", however when I attempt to install it, it tells that it is incompatible with VS2015.  I have been unable to locate a version of those tools intended for 2015.  If someone could point me in the right direction to solve this dilemma, I would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, I am not too late to answer your question.*(almost two years)*..

I faced similar issue as you mentioned in question. In my case I was unable to open `.dfproj` file. I downloaded [Microsoft Azure DataFactory Tools for Visual Studio 2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzureDataFactory.MicrosoftAzureDataFactoryToolsforVisualStudio2015) from Microsoft market place. Installed it to my machine. Now .dfproj file is loading.

```
Microsoft VS Professional 2015
VS2015 version: 14.0.25431 update 3
```